# Are Mad Science Prosthetics viable in Deadlands?

Tags: deadlands-classic

Can a Mad Scientist use his craft to make functional prosthetic limbs for paying customers?

In context, I'm building a Mad Scientist character who is both the party medic and has a day job serving as the town doctor, using his Alchemy and Mad Science engineering to give himself an edge in that regard (Basically he's Dr. Zed from the Borderlands games). Should the need arise, would it be plausible to craft mechanical replacement limbs for patrons, or would low Reliability or other rules prohibit this?

Comment: Prosthetics are available in Reloaded, but only through Smith and Robards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Classic box set (also available as a PDF) City O' Gloom has a 32 page booklet detailing the exact rules you are looking for

Comment: ...and those rules would be?